# Как сделать фон чтобы градиентом передовал цвет картинки (см. скрин)?

Tags: xcode, ios, дизайн, objective-c

Как сделать фон чтобы градиентом передовал цвет картинки (см. скрин)?

https://yadi.sk/i/kv2GUPq9Ww6a9

https://yadi.sk/i/1l2f6QDdWw6c7

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так, только задашь свою картинку как ту, коротая отображается.

Вкратце смысл такой: ты создаешь фоновый `UIImageView(bgImageView)`, кладешь туда свою картинку, а сверху добавляешь `UIToolbar` с фреймом твоего бэкграунда и выставляешь тип (Style) этого `UIToolbar`.

```
UIToolbar* bgToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    bgToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [self.bgImageView insertSubview:bgToolbar belowSubview:self.bgImageView];
```

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось, А возможно чтоб был более насыщен, какой то бледный получается, скрин прикладываю.
https://yadi.sk/i/X6zNDmBDWwrDN

Comment: такой фичи пока не знаю(не искал), но мне интересно решение, если кто подскажет.

Comment: bgToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack?

Comment: )))тоже рассматривал---но разница на лицо, см. картинку
https://yadi.sk/i/yarKjo7AX3cNn

Comment: @SergeyXcode @Anastasia Вот нашел случайно, если кому понадобится. Можно менять и прозрачность и цвет.

https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView